# Provider org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryConnector could not be instantiated

Tags: grails, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am working on a grails 2.5.3 app that will be deployed to cloudfoundry. The app is bound with few services and in order to get the values for those services I use two connectors:

```
//s3 service connector
compile ("org.cloudfoundry.community:spring-cloud-s3-service-connector:1.0.0") {
    excludes "aws-java-sdk", 'slf4j-api', 'slf4j-log4j12', 'slf4j'
}     
//sso service connector
compile (group: 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-sso-connector', version: '1.1.0.RELEASE') {
    excludes 'slf4j-api', 'slf4j-log4j12', 'slf4j'
}
```

When I use both of these I get an error in my application:

> org.springframework.cloud.CloudConnector: Provider
>   org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryConnector could not
>   be instantiated
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator.(Lorg/springframework/cloud/cloudfoundry/Tags;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
>           at io.pivotal.spring.cloud.SsoServiceInfoCreator.(SsoServiceInfoCreator.java:11)

I believe the error is happening because each of these services have a `services` folder under `META-INF` and apparently only one is picked when both of these are used simultaneously.

The `META-INF/services` folder for both is here:

SSO Connector: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-sso-connector/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/services

S3 Connector: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/spring-cloud-s3-service-connector/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/services

I'm not sure how to resolve this error. I've tried various combinations but none seem to work.

**Update**

I've added a second question that is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976791/common-dependency-for-two-packages-gets-dropped-when-both-pages-are-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple Connector extension libs on the classpath is common, each with their own `META-INF/services`. This shouldn't be a problem.

In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976791/common-dependency-for-two-packages-gets-dropped-when-both-pages-are-used), you have:

```
compile ("org.cloudfoundry.community:spring-cloud-s3-service-connector:1.0.0") {
    excludes "aws-java-sdk", 'slf4j-api', 'slf4j-log4j12', 'slf4j'
}
//dependency tree shows 
+--- org.cloudfoundry.community:spring-cloud-s3-service-connector:1.0.0
|    \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:1.0.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:1.0.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3
```

and

```
compile (group: 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-sso-connector', version: '1.1.0.RELEASE') {
    excludes 'slf4j-api', 'slf4j-log4j12', 'slf4j', 'spring-cloud-starter-oauth2'
}
//dependency tree shows
+--- io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-sso-connector:1.1.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.1.1.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:1.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:1.1.1.RELEASE
```

This shows that `spring-cloud-s3-service-connector:1.0.0` transitively depends on `spring-cloud-core:1.0.0.RELEASE`, while `spring-cloud-sso-connector:1.1.0.RELEASE` depends on `spring-cloud-core:1.1.1.RELEASE`. The build system will only pull in one version of `spring-cloud-core`, and it appears that `spring-cloud-core:1.0.0.RELEASE` is the one that is actually getting pulled in and `spring-cloud-sso-connector` isn't compatible with that older version.

There is a `spring-cloud-s3-service-connector:1.1.0` available in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.cloudfoundry.community%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-cloud-s3-service-connector%22), try upgrading to that version.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used `spring-cloud-s3-service-connector:1.1.0` which in-turn is using `spring-cloud-core:1.2.1.RELEASE`. Now everything works as expected.