# Cannot cast object 'org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo@31f7615f' to class 'com.acme.oauth.SsoServiceInfo'

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I have a grails application that I am trying to bind to SSO service. I can see the following when I do `cf env myapp`.

```
"p-identity": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "auth_domain": "https://someurl",
     "client_id": "968c",
     "client_secret": "b44df"
    },
    "label": "p-identity",
    "name": "sso",
    "plan": "ssotest",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
```

In an effort to bind with the service I use the following springcloud libs:

```
compile (group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector', version: '1.2.3.RELEASE' ) {
    excludes 'slf4j-api', 'slf4j-log4j12', 'slf4j'
} 

compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector', version: '1.2.3.RELEASE'
```

Then I create two classes: `SsoServiceInfo` and `SsoServiceInfoCreator`

SsoServiceInfo.java

```
package com.acme.cfservice;
import org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo;

public class SsoServiceInfo extends BaseServiceInfo {

    public static final String P_SSO_ID = "p-identity";
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private String authDomain;

    public SsoServiceInfo(String clientId, String clientSecret, String authDomain) {
        super(P_SSO_ID);
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        this.authDomain = authDomain;
    }

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public String getClientSecret() {
        return clientSecret;
    }

    public String getAuthDomain() {
        return authDomain;
    }
}
```

SsoServiceInfoCreator.java

```
package com.acme.cfservice;
import org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator;
import org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.Tags;

import java.util.Map;

public class SsoServiceInfoCreator extends CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator<SsoServiceInfo> {

    public SsoServiceInfoCreator() {
        super(new Tags());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Map<String, Object> serviceData) {
        return serviceData.get("label").equals(SsoServiceInfo.P_SSO_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public SsoServiceInfo createServiceInfo(Map<String, Object> serviceData) {
        Map<String, Object> credentials = getCredentials(serviceData);
        String clientId = (String) credentials.get("client_id");
        String clientSecret = (String) credentials.get("client_secret");
        String authDomain = (String) credentials.get("auth_domain");
        return new SsoServiceInfo(clientId, clientSecret, authDomain);
    }
}
```

I create a file called `org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator` in `web-app/META-INF/services` and put the following line in it

```
com.acme.cfservice.SsoServiceInfoCreator
```

**Question**

However, when I deploy my application, I get an error on the following line of code:

```
def ssoService = (SsoServiceInfo) new CloudFactory().cloud?.getServiceInfo("sso");
```

The error I get is:

> OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
>   cast object
>   'org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo@6d2369a8' with
>   class 'org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo' to class
>   'com.acme.oauth.SsoServiceInfo'

What should I be doing different here? My class `SsoServiceInfo` clearly extends `org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo`, then why am I getting a `CastException`?

Comment: The `BaseServiceInfo` you're getting back is not a `SsoServiceInfo` object (so can't be cast to one)...  What is it?  What does `println new CloudFactory().cloud?.getServiceInfo("sso").getClass()` show you?

Comment: It prints this: `class org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo`

Comment: @tim_yates `new CloudFactory().cloud?.getServiceInfo('rabbitmq').getClass()` prints `class org.springframework.cloud.service.common.AmqpServiceInfo`. Whereas `new CloudFactory().cloud?.getServiceInfo('mysql').getClass()`  prints `class org.springframework.cloud.service.common.MysqlServiceInfo`. Finally, `new CloudFactory().cloud?.getServiceInfo('sso').getClass()` prints `class org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SsoServiceInfoCreator.accept` method isn't consistent with the payload you show. Specifically, there is no "label" in your payload. Therefore  `FallbackBaseServiceInfoCreator.java` kicks in creating `BaseServiceInfo`. You may want to use some other attributes of the service payload to implement the `accept` method.

Comment: I didn't show the entire payload in the question to save space. I've uploaded the question now with the entire payload. The payload shows `label` as `p-identity`

Comment: In that case, something else is not quite right. Can you print `serviceData` in  `SsoServiceInfoCreator.accept`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried printing the value of accept but nothing shows up. I believe this is because I have this in a Grails application and it might not be printed. However, the reason I was making my own service info was because I was having issues using an OSS service connector. Scott was able to help me out on that question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42974820/654203. Thanks again